# Why there is no database diagram folder inside my database in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I entered username: 'sa' and password:' ' to login. Inside master database there is no database diagram folder:

[image]

I checked [this link on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8234ef86-3066-4208-a6e2-ef3323fa0847/database-diagrams-not-shown?forum=sqlsecurity) and even tried running SQL Server Management Studio (Express), select the database you want to interact with.. rx click and access it's properties.. in the "Files" tab, set the database owner as required.'

But it did not worked.

Comment: There are no database diagrams for system databases.

Comment: You really shouldn't be putting any of your own tables inside the master db.

Comment: why are you putting tables inside "master" instead of creating your own db?? This is not a good idea.

Comment: I have created 19 tables for my project.Already defined relationships now what can I do?

Comment: Script them, Delete them from the master but be carefull mess up master and you reinstall server then create new database and run create scripts on new database.